# Visual Studio 2010: Search within Team Explorer query results without modifying the query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Imagine you have a query that looks like this.

[image]

and it returns all the items whose title contains the string **"fixed"**. However, I'd like to refilter the results further - for example, searching for another string in the title (ex. **ListBox**). Is it possible to do that without modifying editing the query and adding another And clause? I need something quick - like pressing for example CTRL + F and typing the string I need to find in the results of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another great option here is the integration with Excel.  Just connect to TFS through the "Team" tab, and run your query.  You can then use the built-in Excel filtering and sorting tools as you need to, make changes, and re-publish them to the TFS server.

We use this functionality extensively.

Comment: Integration with Excel does the job perfectly...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you check out the Search Work Items for TFS 2010 from VS Code Gallery?

*This extension creates a search box in a Visual Studio 2010 toolbar and Team menu which is used to pull up a work item directly by its ID or search through work items based on text entered.*

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3f31bfff-5ecb-4e05-8356-04815851b8e7

Comment: This extension searches globally through all work items in TFS though, not in current query results. This makes it not very useful.